# properties sheet view eclipse rcp check input

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

In my application (based on Eclipse RCP) I have a model object called `A`:

```
A  
String name;   
String description;
```

In my application, I use properties sheet in a view. 
To work with properties sheet the A object has an adapter which implements IPropertySource.
In this properties view  I can see my object and it's name and description, I can also modify it. I would like to restrict the modification. For example, I don't want diacritic char in the name.

Does properties sheet in Eclipse RCP have a way to check input?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with this myself, but check out [PropertyDescriptors](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/views/properties/IPropertySource.html#getPropertyDescriptors%28%29).

I think you can create a cell editor that will do the editing that you want.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you can override the setPropertyValue method of your adapter (the class implementing IPropertySource) and check the given value there. If you do not like the value / it has the wrong form or value, just do not set the value (or basically reject the value).

```
@Override
public void setPropertyValue(Object id, Object value) {
    if (id.equals(YOUR_SPECIFIED_ID)) {

        //
        // check if value is valid here
        // 

        if (IS_VALID) {
            deviceEntity.setName((String)value);
        }
    } 
}
```